# "Modulation" effect of collector current on DC current gain

Tags: bjt

I've found that it is typical for a BJT NPN transistor to exhibit current gain \$h_{FE}\$ which varies up and down as \$I_C\$ increases. The reason is probably trivial, but for some reason intuition tells me that \$h_{FE}\$ should decrease monotonically with \$I_C\$.

This image is taken from a 2N3904 datasheet.

[image]

Comment: I've written much about this already on this site. When I get to a PC, I'll link you over to them.

Comment: You might start with just getting familiar with the [Three Equivalent Level-1 (DC) Ebers-Moll Models](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/252199/38098) of the BJT. Nothing there for your question. But it's worth a look, just the same. The actual answer is found in this [Discussion and Chart of Collector Current Regions I, II, and III of BJT and Effects](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/357987/38098). It's detailed enough, I hope. (I could repost the stuff here, but it seems redundant to me.)

Comment: It's not trivial http://www.eng.auburn.edu/~niuguof/mextram/_downloads/MextramDefinition.pdf